# Spark access nested column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nested

I want to access a column which contains a nested array similar to [Spark combine columns as nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239887/spark-combine-columns-as-nested-array)

```
columnsMap
res95: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Array[Double]]] = Map(col1 -> Map(A -> WrappedArray(0.5, 0.6666666666666666), d -> WrappedArray(0.25, 0.3333333333333333), c -> WrappedArray(0.25, 1.0)), col2 -> Map(a -> WrappedArray(0.0, 0.0), g -> WrappedArray(0.0, 0.0), B -> WrappedArray(0.5, 0.6666666666666666), c -> WrappedArray(0.25, 1.0), d -> WrappedArray(0.25, 1.0)), col3TooMany -> Map(C -> WrappedArray(0.75, 0.6), jkl -> WrappedArray(0.0, 0.0), t -> WrappedArray(0.25, 1.0)))

scala> columnsMap.get("col1").get.get("A")
res96: Option[Array[Double]] = Some(WrappedArray(0.5, 0.6666666666666666))
```

How can I access the `WrappedArray` in plain Scala?

```
scala> columnsMap.get("col1").get.get("A").get
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [D
  ... 42 elided
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getOrElse to avoid working directly with Options:

```scala
val columnsMap = Map("col1" -> Map("A" -> Seq(1.0, 2.0)))
val nestedArray = columnsMap.getOrElse("col1", Map()).getOrElse("A", Seq(0.0))
```

Then, to get the first element, you can do:

```scala
nestedArray.head
```

Or, if at collecting the rows you did not properly typed the array to Seq, you may need to do:

```scala
nestedArray.asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]].head
```

But the ideal should be to collect with the right type. For instance, if you used a `row.getAs` at some point, it should be:

```scala
row.getAs[Map[String, Map[String, Seq[Double]]]](colName)
```

Comment: Your first solution returns: Any = WrappedArray(0.5, 0.6666666666666666)
How could I access the first double value?

Comment: As Array is of type WrappedArray e.g. no real Array it is unclear to me how to access it.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Leaving like that, you can have an empty Array, so you need to test for it. You can do `nestedArray.headOption` to get an Option[Double] which you can then test for emptiness. Alternatively, you can just change the second `getOrElse` to `getOrElse("A", Array(0.0))` to make sure the array is not empty, then you can just do `nestedArray.head`.

Comment: this does not work e.g. `columnsMap.getOrElse("col1", Map()).getOrElse("A", Array(0.0)).head
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [D
  ... 42 elided
`

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Try `nestedArray.toArray.head` or `nestedArray.toList.head`

Comment: same issues prevail.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler How did you collect this Map from the DataFrame?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler At some point, you collected it as [Array[Double]] type. Instead, it should be [Seq[Double]].

Comment: I collected Map[String, Array[Double]]. Your suggested fix doesn't work, it still stays a `Any = WrappedArray(0.5, 0.6666666666666666)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131061/discussion-between-daniel-de-paula-and-georg-heiler).