# Spark SQL converting a scala DataFrame into a column list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to convert a spark sql Dataframe into an org.apache.spark.sql.Column containing a List?

Each row in the dataframe will be an element in the list.

Comment: Question is unclear: first, a `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` is just "metadata", it doesn't hold actual data. Do you mean you want to convert a DataFrame with one column and multiple records into a new DataFrame with one _record_ and one _column_, where the column is of type List? Why would you want to do that? Doing so would force Spark to contain all data in one node, essentially rendering Spark's distributed abilities useless.

Comment: don't post data/code in comments, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46591305/edit) your post to include this info.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**
Since DataFrames are (weakly) typed, and **there is no ListType**, a Column can not wrap a List.

What it can be, is an ArrayType. That [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239887/spark-combine-columns-as-nested-array) has already been answered.